# What is the right way to check a switch parameter

Tags: powershell

What is the right way to check value of a switch?

```
function testSwitch
{
    Param(
        [switch] $swth
    )

    Write-Host "Value of swth is $swth"

    if($swth.IsPresent){
        Write-host "Switch is present"
    }
    if($swth){
        Write-Host "Switch is present"
    }

}

testSwitch -swth
```

I know both if statement works fine, but how?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**`$swth.IsPresent` and `$swth` can be used *interchangeably***, because in a Boolean context (such as an `if` conditional) `$swth` (an instance of type [`[switch]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.switchparameter) representing a [switch parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6#switch-parameters)) effectively returns the value of the `.IsPresent` property.<sup>[1]</sup>

In fact, **`$swth` is probably preferable**<sup>[2]</sup>, not just for concision, but because the `.IsPresent` property is somewhat confusingly named:

`.IsPresent` doesn't indicate the *presence* of the switch per se, but whether its  *value is `$true`*.

While specifying a switch by itself - `-swth` - implies *both*, the same isn't true if you explicitly set it to `$false`: Passing `-swth:$false` makes `.IsPresent` return `$false`, even though the switch is clearly *present*.

Passing `$false` explicitly isn't common, but has its uses, such as when opting out of a confirmation prompt with `-Confirm:$false`, and when *programmatically* constructing arguments.

Therefore, **if you want to distinguish between the user *not passing* the switch and the user *passing it with value `$false`*, `.IsPresent` won't help you - you'll have to use `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('swth')`**

---

<sup>[1] On conversion to Boolean, which happens in method [`LanguagePrimitives.IsTrue()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/bbd54c317e01d652081753a9cd2350e96aa8bd3e/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L1013), PowerShell calls a `[switch]` instance's [`.ToBool()` method](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/bbd54c317e01d652081753a9cd2350e96aa8bd3e/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCmdlet.cs#L108), which in turn returns the private backing variable behind the `.IsPresent` property.</sup>

<sup>[2] The only caveat is that you must be aware that `$swth` is not a Boolean (`[bool]`), but of type `[switch]`, which may matter in other contexts.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

It would be more simple to just use an `if`/`else` clause:

```
Function Get-FruitDetails {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param (
        [String]$Fruit,
        [Switch]$Yellow
    )

    Write-Verbose "Get fruit details of $Fruit"

    $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Fruit  = $Fruit
        Yellow = $null
    }

    if ($Yellow) {
        Write-Verbose 'Color is yellow'
        $Result.Yellow = $true
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose 'Color is not yellow'
        $Result.Yellow = $false
    }

    $Result
}

Get-FruitDetails -Fruit 'Banana' -Yellow -Verbose
Get-FruitDetails -Fruit 'Kiwi' -Verbose
```

This will output the following:

```
Fruit   Yellow
-----   ------
Banana  True
Kiwi    False
```

Some tips:

- Avoid using `Write-Host`, it's meant for console programs. You're better of using `Write-Verbose` and adding the `-Verbose` switch if you want to see the messages
- Try to use PowerShell approved verbs for function names. These can be easily found using `Get-Verb`. It will make it easier for others to see what your function does `Get`, `Set`, `Remove`, ...

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, which is about contrasting the syntax forms `$swth.IsPresent` and `$swth` to check a switch's value in conditionals.