# Switch Parameter in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, switch-statement

I've been looking all over, and i cant  seem to find the way to make this work the way i want it to.

I'm new to PS Parameters and have something i think should be fairly simple...I want to be able to run a script and detect whether or not the switch is present. Such as:

```
myscript.ps1 -Deploy
```

-or-

```
myscript.ps1
```

Code, that i've been playing with:

```
function start-script {
    param (
        [parameter()]
        [switch]$Deploy
    )
    if ($Deploy.IsPresent) {
        Write-Host "True"
    }
    else {
    Write-Host "False"
    }
}
    
start-script
```

Running, this doesnt return any errors, but does not output the results of the write-host either. It basically does nothing. What am i doing wrong, and how would i get the correct outputs?

Thanks.
M

EDIT: Adding Screenshot of what i am experiancing, since a few have said it should work or work with removing the `.isPresent`

[image]

Comment: Your function works just fine, not sure exactly what's the problem. Are you calling your ps1 file from CLI? like `.\myscript.ps1 -Deploy` ?

Comment: I am. I started calling it from Powershell rather than the PS ISE. And it seems to be returning False no matter what now.

`.\testParam.ps1 -Deploy`
`False`
`.\testParam.ps1`
`False`

Comment: If you want to determine whether the parameter value was *specified* in the function call you can inspect the keys in the ```$PSBoundParameters``` variable - e.g. ```$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey(“Deploy”)```. If you just want to know if the caller wants the switch to be enabled or not you can simply use ```$Deploy``` - Powershell will assign the default value if the user doesn’t specify it in the upstream call.

Comment: To assign a value to a switch parameter when *calling* a function or script you use a slightly different syntax to regular parameters - if you want it to be false you can just omit it, and if you want it to be true you just say ```-Deploy```. You can also do ```-Deploy:$true``` or ```-Deploy:$false``` or even ```-Deploy:$myBoolVariable```

Comment: Remove the `ispresent`. A switch parameter is to return a Boolean if specified so nothing else should be needed: `if ($Deploy){...`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57784149/14903754

Comment: I added a screenshot. Of what i have and what its outputting. Are those results expected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Makes sense, this is because in your function call (the last line of your script) you're never giving the function any argument. If you want to pass an argument to your ps1 script from an outside source you should add a `param(...)` block at the top of your script. I'm following with the code you already have but, in this case, I don't think a function is needed at all.

Code could be simplified to this:

```bash
param (
    [switch] $Deploy
)

if ($Deploy) {
    Write-Host "True"
    return
}

Write-Host "False"
```

But if you want to use a function:

```bash
param (
    [switch] $Deploy
)

function Start-Script {
    param (
        [switch] $Deploy
    )
     
    if ($Deploy) {
        Write-Host "True"
        return
    }

    Write-Host "False"
}

Start-Script @PSBoundParameters
```

- ***From PowerShell:***

```bash
PS /> .\script.ps1
False

PS /> .\script.ps1 -Deploy
True
```

- ***From CMD:***

```bash
D:\> powershell -File script.ps1
False

D:\> powershell -File script.ps1 -Deploy
True
```

#### Edit

To add a bit more context to the answer:

- `[switch] $Deploy` only exist in the scope of your function this is why we add the `param(...)` block at the top of the script too, **so that the function can be invoked with the same arguments as you have invoked the `.ps1` script.**
- Splatting with [`$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psboundparameters) can work with multiple functions.

**Example:**

```bash
param (
    [switch] $Deploy,
    [string] $Name
)

function Start-Script {
    param (
        [switch] $Deploy
    )

    "Deploy switch is: {0}" -f $Deploy.IsPresent
}

function SayHello {
    param(
        [string] $Name
    )

    "Hello $Name!"
}

# This is what mclayton was referring to in their comment.
# If the Argument $Name is called:
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Name')) {
    # Call the function
    SayHello @PSBoundParameters
}

Start-Script @PSBoundParameters
```

- ***From PowerShell:***

```bash
PS /> .\script.ps1 -Name world -Deploy
Hello world!
Deploy switch is: True
```

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler:

```
function Test {
param (
    [switch]$Deploy
)
$Deploy.IsPresent
}
```

[image]